# Arrow keys do not work in bootstrap-combobox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, combobox

Has anyone experienced this with [Bootstrap-combobox project](https://github.com/danielfarrell/bootstrap-combobox)? If I type the first few letters, the dropdown appears with the filtered list of items. Now if I press down arrow, selection goes down as it should, but when I go down further, the list doesn't scroll up. Instead the selection goes out of the visible area. Any fix for this?

(The following image shows the issue. As you press DOWN key, selection goes out of the view and the list doesn't scroll up.)

[image: Scroll Issue Image]

Answer (score 0):

I made a fix for this, maybe not the best, but here is it:

In the "bootstrap-combobox.js" --not the minified version-- find the "move function" (line 317 on version 1.1.6) and replace the cases for "up arrow key" and "down arrow key" with this:

```
      case 38: // up arrow

      var list = $(e.target.nextSibling.children);
      var index = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if ($(list[i]).hasClass('active')) {
            index = i;
        }
      }
      if (index <= (this.$menu.scrollTop()/26)) {
        this.$menu.scrollTop((index-1)*26)
      } 
      e.preventDefault();
      this.prev();
      break;

    case 40: // down arrow
      e.preventDefault();
      this.next();
      var list = $(e.target.nextSibling.children);
      var index = 0;

      for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if ($(list[i]).hasClass('active')) {
            index = i;
        }
      }
      if (index > (this.$menu.scrollTop()/26)+10) {
        this.$menu.scrollTop((index-10)*26)
      }
      break;
```